# Converting a string into integers then find max sum of a consecutive pair of Integers C++

Tags: c++

I have been working on a USACO problem and devised this (see below) algorithm for some test cases. However, for the input "brbrrrbbbrrrrrbrrbbrbbbbrrrrb", I am getting 9. I don't understand how this can be possible. Can anyone help me find the problem.

P.S: These are the outputs of first loop without any values in the second loop:
-10
-10
-10
3
3
5
-10
2
2
-10
4
4
-10
0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string necklace;
    cin >> necklace;
    vector <int> neck;
    int c_it = 0;

 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < necklace.length(); i++){
            if(necklace[i] == necklace[i+1] | 'w' == necklace[i+1]){

            c_it++;

        }

        else{
            if (c_it >= 1){
             cout << c_it+1 << endl;  
            }
            else{
            cout << "-10" << endl; 
            }
            c_it = 0;
        }

    }

int maximum = 0;

for(int i=0; i < neck.size(); i++){
        for(int j=1; j<= neck.size(); j++){
            int valueToCompare = neck[i] + neck[j];

            if(valueToCompare > maximum){
                maximum = valueToCompare;
            }

            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

  cout << maximum;

}
```

Comment: Just step through your code in a debugger, or write down on paper what it does at each step until you see the problem.  That's all we would be doing anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and can't see why. Just trying to get outside opinions.

Comment: Hange `|` to `||` in the first `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have an error is because of the "|" in your first if statement. It should be the boolean operator "||" instead.